# Define css if javascript is not enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to define `.exampleclass img {height:250px}` if javascript is not enabled. Is their anyway to undo this in javascript / jquery?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/scripting

Comment: As of recently all (major) browsers support the [@media scripting](https://caniuse.com/?search=scripting) query

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could probably use HTML's `noscript` tag.

```
<noscript>
    <style type="text/css">
        .exampleclass img {height:250px}
    </style>
</noscript>
```

---

**EDIT**: I'm going to actually side with Stephen's answer as being the best. While the above might work, it might not be valid/following best practices.

Stephen answered:

> put a "no-js" class on your body element, and then remove it with JS at load, and use .no-js in the selector for your CSS

The class could also be placed on your `html` element and then all styling that should appear when JavaScript is not available can be prefixed with `html.no-js` before what the selector would be otherwise. This is what [HTML5 Boiler Plate](http://html5boilerplate.com) does, for example.

Comment: I believe you can place it within the head tags. It would probably be best to define the style in the head. Edit: If it is overriding the class definition, make sure that this is after the other class is defined.

Comment: While this works, I actually recommend alex's solution over this one.

Answer (score 16):

put a "no-js" class on your body element, and then remove it with JS at load, and use .no-js in the selector for your CSS

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
<noscript>
    <style type="text/css">
        .exampleclass img {height:250px}
    </style>
</noscript>
```

[**`Noscript`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.3.1)

Answer (score 7):

[Media scripting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/scripting)  is finally [available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/scripting#browser_compatibility)

```css
p {
  color: lightgray;
}

@media (scripting: none) {
  .script-none {
    color: red;
  }
}

@media (scripting: initial-only) {
  .script-initial-only {
    color: red;
  }
}

@media (scripting: enabled) {
  .script-enabled {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="script-none">You do not have scripting available. :-(</p>
<p class="script-initial-only">Your scripting is only enabled during the initial page load. Weird.</p>
<p class="script-enabled">You have scripting enabled! :-)</p>
```

Comment: Looks like support for this landed in all major browsers (except Samsung Internet) late last year!

Answer (score 5):

Best not to mess with CSS via JS in that way.  Try this:

```
<noscript>

    <link href="no-js.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

</noscript>
```

Answer (score 3):

I use something like this...

#### JavaScript

```
document.body.className += ' javascript';
```

#### jQuery

```
$('body').addClass('javascript');
```

#### CSS

```
.exampleclass img {height: 250px}

.javascript .exampleclass img {height: 500px}
```

Comment: [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript), `style` within `noscript` within `head` is valid.

Comment: @JoshKelley Good to know, I don't know where I got that piece of information from. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant way is to have in your CSS something like:

```
.exampleclass img {height:250px}
.js .exampleclass img {height:auto;}
```

and in your JS:

```
var dd = document.documentElement;
dd.className += ((dd.className == "") ? "js" : " js");
```

so that the second CSS rule will override the first one in case JS is enabled

Answer (score 1):

In the future (if and when browsers start supporting it), it will be possible to use the [`scripting` CSS media feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/scripting):

```css
@media (scripting: none) {
  // Styles to apply if JS is disabled
}
```