# Is there a css selector that will apply if javascript is not enabled?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there css selector that applies if javascript is not available? I do not ask about the no script tag but css.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define css if javascript is not enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665748/define-css-if-javascript-is-not-enabled)

Answer (score 2):

There is no actual "selector" to check if javascript is enabled in css.

Still, I think you might find [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4665769/2824100) helpful. It suggests to put a "no-js" class on the body, and then remove it with a simple script. If javascript is disabled, you will be able to use `body.no-js` as a "selector".